# Add expandable list view as a header or footer view to another expandable list view inside a drawer layout

Tags: android, expandablelistview, drawerlayout

I am creating a application that require multiple expandable list view. So i have a doubt is their any way we can we can add expandable list view as a header or footer to another list view.

Comment: I don't think so. In general you should never put two scrollable view inside each other.

Comment: @sonic I have a long expandable list view how to add headers in between. that  is non clickable text view in between

Comment: You probably should modify your adapter and have `getView` return a header view for the position of your headers and the content row

Comment: can you share any link or elaborate. I am new to android developement. I have tried overriding but did not succeed

Comment: can you share a link with multiple header between expandable view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have diffenet view type in your ListView. To do so you should have an adapter like this :

```
public class YourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private static int HEADER_TYPE = 0;
     private static int CONTENT_TYPE = 1;

     //to make your header not clickable
     @Override
     public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
          return getItemViewType(position) == CONTENT_TYPE;
     }

     @Override
     public int getViewTypeCount() {
          return 2;
     }

     @Override
     public int getItemViewType(int position) {
          if (header)
              return HEADER_TYPE;
          else
              return CONTENT_TYPE;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
           if (getItemViewType(position) == HEADER_TYPE) {
                   //make header view
           } else {
                  //make content view
                  //be careful position is the position in the list view
           }
           return convertView;
      }
}
```

You should be careful when accessing your datas in getView, the postion is the position in the ListView.